# cocos2d ccTouchMoved detect sprite colision only on one side

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

In the game Flight Control, planes can land only if they come from the right side of the airfield. How does that work? Where to begin?

I have a sprite that I can control with path drawing. Now I want to "land" my sprite when it comes to the right side of the airfield.

Comment: You can find a solution to that in my Line-Drawing Game Starterkit (http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/line-drawing-game-starterkit/). You need to get the direction vector from the air strip location to the location of the plane, then check if the vector's angle is within the defined angle from which planes can approach the landing strip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more data on your problem, I can guess this:

Once you detect a collision with the airstrip sprite, compare the coordinates of the plane sprite to those the airstrip sprite, and you should get an idea which side it's on.

What also matters is what direction the plane is going. In Air Control, planes that touch the landing side of the strip don't land unless they are also travelling in the correct direction.

This can be done by comparing your plane sprite's velocity vector to an acceptable landing vector for the airstrip in question, probably using a dot product of the normalized vectors. If the dot product between the two is close enough to 1, then you say it succeeded in landing.